# How to get revZip to create a file and add an item to the archive?

Tags: livecode

Here's the simple handler I'm using to test/learn the revZip library. The fld "XML" contains XML as text.
I just can't see the error... Any ideas?

```
command SaveIssue
    put fld "XML" into tXML
    ask file "Save as:" with "NewIssue.zip" as sheet; CheckResult the result
    put it into tPath
    revZipOpenArchive tPath, "write"; CheckResult the result
    revZipAddItemWithData tPath, "issue.xml", tXML; CheckResult the result
    revZipCloseArchive tPath; CheckResult the result
end SaveIssue

command CheckResult tResult
   if tResult is not empty then
      if tResult is "Cancel" then exit to top
      answer "Error:" && tResult
      exit to top
   end if
end CheckResult
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in an old forum post. The revZip external requires quotes around variable names. Kind of weird, but this change to this line fixes it:

```
revZipAddItemWithData tPath, "issue.xml", "tXML"
```